# How to setup automatically increase my primary key in Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I am beginner in Microsoft Dynamic NAV.

So, I want to find out how to make my Primary Key in my table to be auto increment.

For example I have table with next Line: "`Field No.= 10" "Field name = Code" -"Type = Code" "Lenght = 10";`

I want that every time someone puts a new user, that my code to increase by `10`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would create a no. series. 
In your code you should use the standard NAV codeunit NoSeriesManagement (396).

This code would look something like:

```
NewNo := gCuNoSeriesMngmnt.GetNextNo('No series code',WORKDATE,TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your table to always increment with 10 you will have to add some code in your table's OnInsert trigger.

I'm assuming that Field No. is your Primary Key

```
// if there is no "Field No." assigned yet
IF "Field No." = '' THEN BEGIN
  // Get the last entry in the table and assign the next number to Field No.
  <RecordVariableOfTable>.FINDLAST;
  "Field No." := <RecordVariableOfTable>."Field No." + 10;
END;
```

RecordVariableOfTable has to be defined as a Record instance of your table in your C/AL global variables for the table.

**If this is your master table and Field No. is your Primary Key**
Then you should implement No. Series functionality on your table and assign a No. Series which increments by 10.